# Detectar error en consulta MySQLi desde PHP, usando procedimiento almacenados

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, stored-procedure

Tengo una pregunta, estoy desarrollando un pequeño PHP para obtener los datos de una consulta en un procedimiento almacenado en MySQL, el problema es que no encuentro la forma de detectar si dicha consulta terminó en error, para en su caso realizar el procedimiento correspondiente en mi PHP. Adjunto mi código PHP, así como mi procedimiento almacenado. De manera voluntaria estoy haciendo un error en mi procedimiento almacenado pero no logro detectar dicho error en mi PHP.

```
<?php

require_once '../constantes.php';
require_once RUTAS_FICHEROS['FuncionesGenerales'];

$conexion = obtenerConexion();

if ($conexion == FALSE) {
    echo "Error de conexión";
} else {

    if (!($sqlResultado = $conexion->query("call bd_secjo.test(50);"))) {
        echo "Consulta fallida"; //Esta es la parte que no logro detectar, estoy generando un error en mi procedimiento pero no imprime "Consulta fallida"
    }

   var_dump($sqlResultado->fetch_assoc());

    desconectarServer($conexion);

}
```

Mi procedimiento almacenado:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`Cliente`@`%` PROCEDURE `test`(num int)

BEGIN

 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
 BEGIN
 SHOW ERRORS LIMIT 1;
RESIGNAL;
 ROLLBACK;
 END; 

 DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING
 BEGIN
 SHOW WARNINGS LIMIT 1;
RESIGNAL;
 ROLLBACK;
 END;

START TRANSACTION;
insert into tblcargos (Cargo) values(num);
select * from tblcargoss; //aquí genero un error voluntario
COMMIT;

END
```

Al hacer vardump en PHP imprime lo siguiente:

```
array(3) { ["Level"]=> string(5) "Error" ["Code"]=> string(4) "1146" ["Message"]=> string(41) "Table 'bd_secjo.tblcargoss' doesn't exist" }
```

Comment: Sinceramente, no creo que lo que intentas hacer aquí amerite un procedimiento almacenado, podrías hacerlo mediante una consulta normal, desde PHP. La ventaja es que descargas un poco más al manejador de base de datos, trasladando la lógica a PHP. De todos modos, puedes verificar si existe la clave `Error` en el array que te está devolviendo, si existe es que en efecto hubo error. Si muestras un `print_r` se podrá ver mejor cómo viene el array y aconsejarte la forma de verificar si hay una clave `Error` dentro de él. Realmente no sé por qué te está dando un array con una clave `Level`

Comment: De hecho, es solo una prueba, en ese procedimiento van a haber varias inserciones simultáneas y debo evitar que vaya a quedarse alguna inserción sin realizarse.